# Replace enter with space

Tags: sql-server-2005, vb.net-2010

How can i replace "Enter" in one of fields in the database with space

actually I have tried the below codes in vb.net, but non of them is working for me ,,

```
 address = Replace(address, System.Environment.NewLine, " ")
```

or

```
address = Replace(address, vbNewLine, " ")
```

or

```
address = Replace(address, Chr(13), "")
```

Language : Vb.net 
database : MSSQL 2005

Thanks in advance

Comment: new lines are \n\r in windows, so try Chr(13) and Chr(10).

Comment: thank you so much ,  Chr(10) works

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to replace new-line chars in SQL-Server.

- Line Feed – CHAR(10)
- Carriage Return – CHAR(13)

So if you want to update a column and replace NewLines with white-spaces:

```
UPDATE TableName SET address=REPLACE(REPLACE(address, CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' ');
```

Answer (score 7):

- Line Feed – CHAR(10)
- Carriage Return – CHAR(13)
- Tab char(9)

  **REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(address, CHAR(13),' '), CHAR(10),' '), CHAR(9),' ')**